# The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists error

Tags: java, spring-mvc

**Web.xml**

Books Management

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>BooksManagement</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>


<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>BooksManagement</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/student.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

My controller is **AddStudentController**

```
@Controller
public class AddStudentController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/student", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView student() {
    return new ModelAndView("student", "command", new Students());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addStudent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addStudent(@ModelAttribute("SpringWeb") Students student,ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("firstName", student.getFirstName());
    model.addAttribute("lastName", student.getLastName());
    model.addAttribute("id", student.getId());

    return "result";
    }
}
```

[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZ3tM.png)

The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists error

Comment: So what's the URL you are requesting?

Comment: At last, I was able to solve the issue. In first I was trying to hit *student.jsp* without hitting in *index.jsp*. After I give *<a href="student">Click here...</a>* in index.jsp. Now it's solved.  Thanks, for looking for my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, I was trying to hit **student.jsp** without hitting in **index.jsp**. After I give `<a href="student">Click here...</a>` in index.jsp.

Also, added

`<welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>`

in web.xml

Now it's solved

As Controller was searching **/student** it was nowhere mentioned

```
@Controller
public class AddStudentController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/student", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView student() {
    return new ModelAndView("student", "command", new Students());
    }
```

Comment: Excellent! Good work on keeping at it until the problem becomes clear and can be resolved. It is not necessary to have "index.jsp" but it sure is necessary to map the relative URL "/student" to some endpoint.